# Docusign PHP Client - Check if a recipient has signed the document

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using the following library for integrating Docusign into my project.
[[docusign-php-client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client)]

Lets say I have sent the document to 2 recipients A and B.  Recipient A has signed the document while recipient B has not yet signed it.

Using the above library **how do I go about checking if user A has signed the document or not**.  I did figure out how to check if the whole Envelope is signed or not.  But this is not what I need.

I want to check **specifically** using the above library if user A has signed the document or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either poll the DocuSign platform to learn the current status of the envelope and its signer fields, or **much better and highly recommended**, have the platform tell your app when someone has signed.

The latter (**highly recommended**) is generically called a webhook.

DocuSign offers webhook subscriptions on either a per envelope or per account basis. Per envelope: this is the `eventNotification` feature of the Envelopes::Create endpoint. Per account: this is the `Connect` feature.

Either way, DocuSign will call your app with the news that a signing recipient has opened the document(s) (this is `delivered` status) or signed the document(s) in the envelope.

You can see how this works via [the Webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status). Here is the [PHP example of the webhook recipe](https://github.com/DocuSign/recipe-010-webhook-php). You can try out the recipe, free, on Heroku. See the recipe page on GitHub.

**Polling the DocuSign Platform for Status**

This technique is not recommended. If you want to do it, note that the platform imposes limits on how often you can poll (no more than once every 15 minutes).

For more information, see the [recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/polling-for-envelope-status).

Comment: I want to poll the server but i cannot find any code snippet using the docusign-php-client library.  I need a code sample specifically using this library if it is possible to do so ofc.

Comment: Sorry, we don't yet have the updated recipe that uses the Php SDK. See recipe link in expanded answer.